# ListView setSelection does not works for selecing simple list

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making a single choice list inside a dialog.

I have completed all the basic functionalities like added a setonitemclicklistener but what i want is to set the first item of list by default, but when i use setSelection(1) it does not work:

i have done :

```
    private void resetPosition(final ListView lv) {
    lv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv.setSelection(1);
        }
    });
   }
```

and i am calling this function on button click which will start this dialog,

What is wrong with this code?

Documentation of setSelection() shows a line "*If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately*" is this the fault?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need item selection, you should allow list items to be checked. You need to set the choice mode of the ListView to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` using `ListView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)`.

Then you need to use `ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked)` method as `ListView.setItemChecked(0, true)` to set the first position as selected.

Also see: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection

Comment: it worked but i want the selected item to be visible when the list is displayed, right now the item is being selected but it is not shown as it is in the bottom of the list. Thanx in advance

Comment: use setSelection() method as you did earlier for that.

Comment: @Mr_Hmp did you find the way?